# Stored Procedure updates two rows

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, mariadb

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_USER_PNTS(USER_ID INT , PNTS INT, QNT INT)
   BEGIN
   DECLARE x  INT DEFAULT 1;
   DECLARE TEMP_GIFT_ID INT;
   UPDATE USR_PNT_SUMM SET USD_PNTS = USD_PNTS + PNTS WHERE USER_ID = 1;
   COMMIT;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

The above stored procedure updates two rows - one for user_id = 1 and the other one for userid 0. I dont understand why!

This is how I call the stored procedure -
CALL GET_USER_PNTS(1, 1, 1)

Please let me know why the user_id 0 is also getting updated.

P.S
1. I am using MariaDB.
2. UserID 0 is what I had manually added in the table. In pratice there won't be any 0 user_id. But even then, the row should not have been updated.

Comment: I guess that in real example you don't have hardcoded `UPDATE USR_PNT_SUMM SET USD_PNTS = USD_PNTS + PNTS WHERE USER_ID = 1;`  but proper parameters.

Comment: I put USER_ID as 1 so as to make sure that only the row for user id 1 gets updated. But I still see other row getting updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please rename your parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_USER_PNTS(L_USER_ID INT , L_PNTS INT, L_QNT INT)
   BEGIN
   DECLARE x  INT DEFAULT 1;
   DECLARE TEMP_GIFT_ID INT;
   UPDATE USR_PNT_SUMM SET USD_PNTS = USD_PNTS + L_PNTS WHERE USER_ID = L_USER_ID;
   COMMIT;
   END //
```

---

Probably `USER_ID = USER_ID` is treated as true.

Comment: This is right on the spot. I wonder how I did not notice this! Thanks a lot though.